# pass class reference between activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an activity Test.java where i declared my custom class PPMDecoder.

the class PPMDecoder uses a listener interface to generate a interupt on the activity (in order to update the UI).

the updateChannelUpperLimits event of the PPMdecoder class is where i periodically put some data that i need on the activity SecondActivity.java. 
the PPMdecoder class generates also other Events that i use in the Test.java that now i removed to make it easy for you.

QUESTION: 
i want to use the data coming from updateChannelUpperLimits event  in the SecondActivity.java that is called upon user request (from option menu).
Note: I can't create a second instance of the PPMdecoder class inside the SecondActivity because i need to use a single instance of the PPMDecoder class (that now i declared in Test.java because i use it taking data from another Event of the PPMdecoder class that i removed from IAsyncFetchListener.java to make it easy for you )

Which is the best way to do it?

1)Could i pass a reference of the class PPMDecoder started on the Test.java Activity to the SecondClass?

2)Or could i update the TextViews of the SecondActivity from the Test.java activity?

3)Or there is a best way to do it in a easy way?

these are the actual files:

filtered version of the Test.java

```
 public class Test extends Activity {

PPMDecoder ppmdecoder;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);


    ppmdecoder=new PPMDecoder(this);
    ppmdecoder.setListener(new IAsyncFetchListener() {

        public void updateChannelUpperLimits(ArrayList<Float> channelUpperLimits ) {
            //Here i receive data to use to update a TextView in a new Activity
        }



    });

    int result=ppmdecoder.startDecoding();

   }

 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    Intent intent;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_decoder_calibration:


            //here i open another activity to show data in a different way          
                intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

 }
```

interface file IAsyncFetchListener.java

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.EventListener;


 public interface IAsyncFetchListener extends EventListener {

void updateChannelUpperLimits(ArrayList<Float> channelUpperLimits );
 //here i declare also other events that i use    

 }
```

filtered version of the class PPMdecoder.java

```
 public class PPMDecoder {
 private ArrayList<Float> channelUpperLimits; //array with upper limits of the channels in milliseconds
IAsyncFetchListener fetchListener = null;

 public void setListener(IAsyncFetchListener listener) {
        this.fetchListener = listener;
    }

public PPMDecoder(Context context)
{
}

  public class RecordAudio extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Throwable> {

    @Override
    protected Throwable doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            while (started) {
                    // Here is where i update the channelUpperLimits ArrayList on each loop.
                    //each 100ms publish the results on the UI
                    elapsedTimeSinceLastPublish=System.currentTimeMillis()-lastPublishMilliseconds;
                    if (elapsedTimeSinceLastPublish>100){
                        publishProgress();
                        lastPublishMilliseconds=System.currentTimeMillis();

                     }

             }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... arg0) {
            //generate interupt in the father thread
            if (fetchListener != null) fetchListener.updateChannelUpperLimits(channelUpperLimits);
        }


} 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want avoid your class have multiple instance i suggest to trasform your PPMDecoder class in singleton, in this case you can call getInstance in every class you need it, without replication. 
So your class class shuold be something like this

```
public class PPMDecoder {
    private static final String TAG = PPMDecoder.class.getSimpleName();
    private ArrayList<Float> channelUpperLimits; //array with upper limits of the channels in milliseconds
    IAsyncFetchListener fetchListener = null;

    public void setListener(IAsyncFetchListener listener) {
        this.fetchListener = listener;
    }

    private static PPMDecoder instance = null;

    protected PPMDecoder(){}

    public static PPMDecoder getInstance(){
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new PPMDecoder();
        return instance;
    }

    ....
    ....
}
```

in any activity you need it just call:

```
PPMDecoder.getInstance().setListener(new IAsyncFetchListener() {

    public void updateChannelUpperLimits(ArrayList<Float> channelUpperLimits ) {
        //Here i receive data to use to update a TextView in a new Activity
    }



});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I didn't understood your entire answer, could you formulate an easy solution for me? i can follow you when you say: declare PPMdecoder class in the Application context. then from the activity i can get the reference to the app context and then i can use the PPMdecoder class contained in the app context. So, at that point, is it possible to just use the PPMdecoder listener in the activities, without modifing anything else?